# I want to take data from CSV file and to put into Two different arrays variables

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, pandas

I have this code in python. Importing CSV file.

```
Location = r'C:\assign\lrdataset.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(Location, names=['Xi','Yi'])
print(df.columns)
```

Print shows this:

```
   Xi          Yi
0   -2.552990 -218.408328
1    1.764052  155.118872
2   -1.791328 -128.884326
3   -1.214077  -91.571734
4   -1.444940 -122.267726
5    0.195070   12.248124
6    1.480515  135.444007
........
```

But i want to take this two input and output values into two different variables, in array forms. Like this.

```
X=np.array([[-2.552990],[1.764052],[-1.791328],[-1.214077]])

Y=np.array([[-218.408328],[155.118872],[-128.884326],[-91.571734]])
```

Comment: That's nice. What have you tried? And where are you getting the values for `X` and `Y`?

Comment: If you didnt understand what am i asking, why did you vote down it?
Data is coming from CSV file. Simple that.   CSV is excel file. That containing 2 columns.

Comment: Concern is not those values of X and Y . Concern is only to representation of Data.

Comment: Back to my original question - what have you tried so far? Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please [edit] your question and post what you have tried so far, including example input, expected output, and the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks.

Comment: What i have tried is front of you .  I have tried this portion of code that is not giving output as i want.  its giving representation in row shape. 
i want to put data into two variables. as i mentioned above in code.

Comment: `X = df.Xi.values`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is that what you want:

```
In [43]: X = df.Xi.reshape((len(df), 1))

In [44]: X
Out[44]:
array([[-2.55299 ],
       [ 1.764052],
       [-1.791328],
       [-1.214077],
       [-1.44494 ],
       [ 0.19507 ],
       [ 1.480515]])
```

if you want to round your values:

```
In [62]: df.Xi.round(5).reshape(len(df), 1)
Out[62]:
array([[-2.55299],
       [ 1.76405],
       [-1.79133],
       [-1.21408],
       [-1.44494],
       [ 0.19507],
       [ 1.48052]])
```

Comment: [  3.55481793e-01]
 [ -5.35270165e-01]
 [ -3.04614305e+00]
 [  1.99300197e-01]
 [  5.19453960e-02]
 [ -8.59307670e-02]
 [ -7.07505698e-01]
 [ -5.54309627e-01]
 [ -7.92286662e-01]
 [ -5.90057646e-01]
 [  6.89818165e-01]
 [ -1.54477110e+00]
 [  1.03493150e-02]
 [ -1.53624369e+00]
 [  8.64436199e-01]

its giving output in shape of these incorrect values in column.

Comment: @JawwadRafiq, try to set format for float values: `pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.5f}'.format`

Comment: i copied this line as it is in my code. but output is same .  [  3.55481793e-01]....         .

Comment: @JawwadRafiq, you may want to check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21008858/formatting-floats-in-a-numpy-array)

Comment: [  3.55480000e-01]
    [ -5.35270000e-01]
    [ -3.04614000e+00]
    [  1.99300000e-01]
    [  5.19500000e-02]
    [ -8.59300000e-02]
    [ -7.07510000e-01]
    [ -5.54310000e-01]
    [ -7.92290000e-01]
    [ -5.90060000e-01]
    [  6.89820000e-01]
    [ -1.54477000e+00]

Comment: @JawwadRafiq, well this has nothing to do with your question. Try to use google asking how to present you numpy float values in desired format

Comment: i do not want to present in any format, i just want to show values as they were showing before .    I wan to print them as it is.

Comment: I am unable to present it in correct format. please help :(

Answer (score 2):

You can try [`reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html) with [`shape`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shape.html):

```
print df.shape
(7, 2)

X = df.Xi.reshape((df.shape[0],1))
print X
[[-2.55299 ]
 [ 1.764052]
 [-1.791328]
 [-1.214077]
 [-1.44494 ]
 [ 0.19507 ]
 [ 1.480515]]

Y = df.Yi.reshape((df.shape[0],1))
print Y
[[-218.408328]
 [ 155.118872]
 [-128.884326]
 [ -91.571734]
 [-122.267726]
 [  12.248124]
 [ 135.444007]]
```

Comment: [ 3.55480000e-01] [ -5.35270000e-01] [ -3.04614000e+00] [ 1.99300000e-01] [ 5.19500000e-02] [ -8.59300000e-02] [ -7.07510000e-01] [ -5.54310000e-01] [ -7.92290000e-01] [ -5.90060000e-01] [ 6.89820000e-01] [ -1.54477000e+00]

Comment: I am unable to present it in correct format. please help :(

Comment: How it works? Still problem? Maybe help [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777783/suppress-scientific-notation-in-numpy-when-creating-array-from-nested-list) - `np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)`

Comment: [ -52.57817499]
 [-268.2346978 ]
 [   2.81502832]
 [  24.85009055]
 [  18.77058224]
 [ -31.35049768]
 [ -29.87467044]
 [ -52.92511068]
 [ -41.7770076 ]

Comment: I am very surprised that you unaccept my solution. I think my comment under this solution help you with formatting problem. Can you explain why you unaccept? Thank you.

Comment: it is working fine , but output in different format.  but its ok.

Comment: Ok, no problem. Nice day.