# numpy printing numeric values in e+12

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a problem using numpy. Basically I am converting data from pandas data-frame to numpy.
data simple :

```
[1503532800000, 4147.0, 4371.68, 4085.01, 4316.01, 787.418753]]
```

to convert to numpy I use the code :

```
Df= df.values
```

the out put is :

```
[1.52098560e+12 9.15192000e+03 9.33378000e+03 8.57000000e+03
 8.69998000e+03 2.39326870e+04]
```

I dont understand what is the problem I using python3.5

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777783/suppress-scientific-notation-in-numpy-when-creating-array-from-nested-list

Answer (score 0):

adding : np.set_printoptions(suppress=True,
   formatter={'float_kind':'{:f}'.format})

to my code solved the output issue