# How to use Pandas with float values

Tags: pandas, matrix

I have data from csv:

```
36849|17|4.7|20180118103240
36792|17|5.3|20180118103238
```

4.7 and 5.3 is float

But when I do like this:

```
scores_data_train = pd.read_csv('../Dataset/TrainData//u.score.csv', sep='|')
scores_train = scores_data_train.as_matrix()
print(scores_train[:1, :])
```

The result:

```
[[3.68490000e+04 1.70000000e+01 4.70000000e+00 2.01801181e+13]]
```

Please help me. Thank you

Comment: Why are you using `as_matrix`? What's the intention here? It looks like the result is exactly correct. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please do the below settings after importing numpy.
  refer [similar questions, please check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777783/suppress-scientific-notation-in-numpy-when-creating-array-from-nested-list)

```
   import numpy as np  
   np.set_printoptions(suppress=True,
   formatter={'float_kind':'{:0.2f}'.format})
```

#float, 2 units #precision right, 0 on left

Comment: The pandas option will not affect the output format of the numpy array returned by `.as_matrix()` - after that point, it's basically out of pandas's hands.

Comment: idea was to use it before converting to a matrix. Will that not work ?

Comment: Unfortunately not - the option only takes effect when floats inside a pandas dataframe are formatted to strings. Calling `.as_matrix()` will turn the dataframe into an array of floats, so pandas display formatting doesn't come into play.

Answer (score 0):

The `as_matrix()` method turns the dataframe into a numpy array, which is limited to a single datatype by definition. You can't have some of the elements treated as floats while others are integers.

As long as you do not call `.as_matrix()`, you will have a dataframe, which can have integer and float columns. The types for each column can be specified by calling `pd.read_csv(..., dtype={"colname": "int", "colname2": "float"})`.