# How can I make array not show e++00 in python?

Tags: python, arrays

Is there any way to make array not show e++0x. It is the consequence from using np.column_stack

```
 f = np.array([[3.00000000e+00, 9.04392878e+00, 8.69169589e+00, 1.20000000e+04, 7.00000000e+00, 
               7.21376000e+07, 3.00000000e+00], [2.00000000e+00, 6.38373979e+00, 
               7.75724682e+00, 1.40000000e+04, 9.00000000e+00, 8.25648000e+07, 
               2.00000000e+00]])
```

For example:

```
f = np.array([[3, 9.04392877641821 , 8.691695889412165, 12000, 7, 72137600, 3],[2,.........]])
```

Thank You

Comment: Can you try `np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)` from [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777783/suppress-scientific-notation-in-numpy-when-creating-array-from-nested-list)?

Comment: np.set_printoptions(suppress=True) is working. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pretty-print a NumPy array without scientific notation and with given precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891790/pretty-print-a-numpy-array-without-scientific-notation-and-with-given-precision)