# How to keep the format of data in a list to be unchanged after converting to array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list called coo. the data in it is like the following:

```
coo: [(0.0, 1.0), (1.0, 0.0)]
coo: [(0.0, 1.0), (1.0, 0.0)]
coo: [(0.0, 1.0), (1.0, 0.0)]
coo: [(0.0, 1.0), (1.0, 0.0)]
coo: [(0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 3.0), (0.0, 5001.0), (1.0, 0.0), (1.0, 3.0), (1.0, 5001.0), (3.0, 0.0), (3.0, 1.0), (3.0, 5001.0), (5001.0, 0.0), (5001.0, 1.0), (5001.0, 3.0)]
coo: [(0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 5001.0), (1.0, 0.0), (1.0, 5001.0), (3.0, 5001.0), (5001.0, 0.0), (5001.0, 1.0), (5001.0, 3.0)]
coo: [(0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 5001.0), (1.0, 0.0), (1.0, 5001.0), (2.0, 3.0), (3.0, 2.0), (3.0, 5001.0), (5001.0, 0.0), (5001.0, 1.0), (5001.0, 3.0)]
```

After I convert it to be an array I see the data becomes like the following:

```
coo: [[0. 1.]
 [1. 0.]]
coo: [[0. 1.]
 [1. 0.]]
coo: [[0. 1.]
 [1. 0.]]
coo: [[0. 1.]
 [1. 0.]]
coo: [[0.000e+00 1.000e+00]
 [0.000e+00 3.000e+00]
 [0.000e+00 5.001e+03]
 [1.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [1.000e+00 3.000e+00]
 [1.000e+00 5.001e+03]
 [3.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [3.000e+00 1.000e+00]
 [3.000e+00 5.001e+03]
 [5.001e+03 0.000e+00]
 [5.001e+03 1.000e+00]
 [5.001e+03 3.000e+00]]
```

Here is my code:

```
          coo=[]
          for r, c in zip(row, col):
            # Get the node name corresponding to the index r
            node_r = next((node for node, index in node_to_index.items() if index == r), None)

            # Get the node name corresponding to the index c
            node_c = next((node for node, index in node_to_index.items() if index == c), None)  
            coo.append((node_r, node_c))
          coo_array = np.array(coo) 
          print('coo:',coo_array)
```

How can I keep the data in coo_array to be the same as in coo for example if there is 1.0 in coo, the same should exist in coo_array?

```
coo_array = np.array(coo,dtype=float)
```

Comment: 1.0 is still in coo_array. You are misunderstanding that the *display* of the numbers in an array is independent from the *value* of the numbers in an array.

Comment: The last `coo` still has floats, just like the others.  It is displayed in 'scientific notation' because the range of values is larger, for example the `5001.0`.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777783/suppress-scientific-notation-in-numpy-when-creating-array-from-nested-list

Comment: Try `print(coo_array.tolist())`.